# What does アタマ mean in reference to food/portion sizes?

Tags: meaning, words

[image]

I came across this at a Yoshinoya and I've never seen this before on a menu. I can't figure out what this is supposed to mean; all I can infer from the pricing is that maybe it's a size in between 並 and 大.

Comment: [This](https://www.yoshinoya.com/_static/page/html/images.6497fde801cd6d4318b5a2c5393e5aeb/1003.pdf) (accessible from [here](https://www.yoshinoya.com/news/2013/index.html)) is the announcement from Yoshinoya about the menu. I hear it used to be among the hidden menu (just like つゆだく) before making its debut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In 牛丼{ぎゅうどん} ("beef bowl"), 「アタマ」 refers to the toppings that are placed over the rice.  In other words, it refers to the stewed beef and onion.

Here, 「アタマ」 refers to the particular size of gyudon consisting of regular-size rice and large toppings, resulting in a "size" between 「並{なみ}」(regular) and 「大盛{おおもり}」(large) in the total amount of food served.  This should explain the pricing for アタマ in the photo above.

Please also note that the "official" size name used at Yoshinoya is 「**アタマの大盛**」.

Hope all this makes sense.  It is a fairly popular gyudon size now as it gives you extra beef without all that extra rice to go with it like 大盛 does.

"**Big head (= extra toppings) on top of the regular-size rice**", so to speak.

Yoshinoya sold 5 million bowls of アタマの大盛 in no time.

[image]

Comment: へえ！初めて見ました。どこの牛丼屋でもやってるんですか。吉野家、すき家、松屋？(ついでになか卯)　ところで牛皿って何

Comment: どこでもあるかどうかはわからん。松屋は確実にある。ワシ自身最近松屋でアタマ食うたさかい。すき家はあったかどうか記憶がない。

Comment: へ～さすが～　（あっ！77777点！すげえぞろ目）

Comment: @Shoko 「牛皿」はご飯なしやねん。要するにアタマオンリーの皿や。て、こんなん説明してたら食いしん坊みたいに見られてまうやんか。

Comment: この「アタマ」は「アタマの大盛り」の略だったような気がしますがどうでしょうか。

Comment: @brokenheadphones その通りでした。情報追加します。