# Question about 「並の上」

Tags: meaning

I am not really sure if I understood the following sentence correctly:

> 「しかも攻撃パワーは**並の上**といったところ！」

The pattern in bold is what makes me struggle here. I found this explanation of the last part of the sentences https://j-nihongo.com/toittatokoroda/, in which **「といったところ」** was described as being used for expression amounts that are not very high. Judging from that I believe that the amount of power is not exceptionally large here. However, the **「並の上」** would be indecipherable to me without the meaning of **「といったところ」**. When checking the dictionary entries I felt like picking exactly what I had to in order to "make the pattern fix the situation".

The problem is matter not very complicated but I feel like I am missing something about the pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「しかも攻撃{こうげき}パワーは並{なみ}の上{うえ}といったところ！」

「並{なみ}」 means "average", "regular", etc.  Look at the image in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43439/what-does-%e3%82%a2%e3%82%bf%e3%83%9e-mean-in-reference-to-food-portion-sizes/43440#43440) where the word is used to indicate the regular-size beef bowl.

「並の上」, therefore, means "**above average**".  The  connotation often associated with this phrase is "**not great**", but without further context, I could not tell if that is the case with the sentence in question.

Seeing 「並の上」 in conjunction with 「といったところ」, however, I would tend to think that the speaker is not too impressed by the attack power.